# How can I grab a value from this string using regEx in c# explain the regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string and I need to parse it for a value...

```
var msg = "Sometext can't do this. Blah blah blah Version id: 'xxx'";
```

How can I use regex and get the text between the last two single quotes? xxx
Notice the first single quote in {can't}
The value I'm seeking will always be between the last set on single quotes.
A brief explanation of the regex would be awesome as well.

Thanks so much for any help, tips, examples.

Comment: How would you know which two single quotes are the correct ones? The last 2 ones? The ones after ":"?

Comment: You need to define the rule first - which '' you need to look for in the given string and how to find that.

Comment: Yes... The value I'm seeking in this instance will always be between the last 2 single quotes in the source string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the final Regex

```
    (?<=')[^']*(?='$)
```

The general pattern I use is

```
    (?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)
```

It finds a pattern that lies between a prefix and a suffix. What we want to find is

```
    [^']*
```

This means anything but the single quote (`'`) repeated zero or more times.

Finally we look for `'$` at the end, not just `'`. This means that the single quote must be at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
'\w*'
```

Its simple to understand, \w - looks for alphanumeric characters , * makes it look for any number of repetitions, and its enclosed in single quotes means looking for anynumber of alphanumeric characters enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In that particular `string`...

```
@"'\w+'"
```

...will match `"'xxx'"`, but if you know the `string` will always end with `"Version id: 'xxx'"` and you want to account for other text that may be surrounded by single quotes, you can use this...

```
@"Version id: '(?<versionId>\w+)'$"
```

...and then retrieve the version ID with this...

```
Match match = Regex.Match(msg, @"Version id: '(?<versionId>\w+)'$");

if (match.Success)
{
    string versionId = match.Groups["versionId"].Value;

    // Perform further processing on versionId...
}
```

The regular expression breaks down like this:

- `Version id: '` = literal text `"Version id: '"`
- `(?<versionId>\w+)` = A group that you can [access by name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bs2twtah.aspx#named_matched_subexpression) (`"versionId"`)
- `\w+` = [One or more occurrences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3206d374.aspx) of a [word character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter) (letters, digits, and punctuation).  If you're looking to match only [decimal digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/20bw873z.aspx#DigitCharacter), you can use `\d+` instead.
- `'` = literal text `"'"`
- `$` = anchors the match to the [end of the line or `string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/h5181w5w.aspx#End)